# How to add GD to a PHP 5.3 CentOS installation from a different repo?

Tags: php, centos, yum, gd

I installed PHP 5.3 on a CentOS 5.3 using yum and repos from Webtatic (http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/) and now I'd like to add the GD library to that installation but Webtatic seems to be offline.

Now:

```
# yum install php-gd
```

Fails of course (not the same PHP version) into: *Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-gd-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64*

And:

```
# yum install php53-gd
```

Fails into *Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common*

How can I add the GD libraries now?

Comment: You can't?  You may need to find a different source for the version of PHP that you need, and then completely re-install PHP, and then include the versions you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove php-common and install php53-common

Also Centos5 has PHP 5.3.3 available, I'd remove the one from Webtatic

Then do "yum install php53"

Hopefully then the dependices will be resolved correctly because you are using ht

Comment: > You need to remove php-common and install php53-common
How do I do this?

Comment: yum install php53

Comment: yum remove php-common

Comment: First remove then install

Answer (score 1):

You need to find and install the package(s) with appropriate version to meet the dependencies. Otherwise, you will have no other choice but to build and install the needed packages from source.