# Removed and then reinstalled php-common via yum. Now no virtual hosts?

Tags: php, linux, virtualhost, yum

Using `yum` I wanted to install the `php-gd`library, however there was a dependency issue with `php-common` preventing me from installing `php-gd`. So after some digging I found [this article](https://serverfault.com/questions/335960/how-to-add-gd-to-a-php-5-3-centos-installation-from-a-different-repo) on SO. I followed the instructions and removed `php-common`. I then reinstalled `php-common`. After that I was able to install `php-gd` without issue. However, I tried loading up my website and I find that the virtual hosts file is not being parsed and only the default site comes up. Even if I croaked the PHP install I would not think that it would mess up the virtual hosts. Or would it? Thanks.

Comment: Seconded. Though FWIW I'd check the Apache logfile and see what it has to say on the matter.

Comment: Thought it might do well on SO because it involved PHP. In any case could someone migrate it over? I don't think I have the privs to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs ? What does the output of `httpd -S` say.

Comment: Posting your (presumably) apache config would help.